# SQL Query to display unique records based on certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-server, relational-database

*[I have gone through a large number of questions before posting this question.]*

I have a table which contains 4 fields. It is *ClientId, ClientName,ClientAddress, ClientCity*.

Now, I have an autocomplete textbox control where I need to fetch & display client name.

The problem is that in our database we have same client from the same city from different address.

Now the requirement given to me is that the user should be able to see "ClientName" or "ClientName + ClientCity" or "ClientName+ClientCity+ClientAddress" to make it easy for user to select the client.

It means that I need to add a column to the query till it makes it unique.

I am sure there must be some simple solution to this which I am not getting for past 2 days now.

As shown in below sample data, If I show only "D" as a client name to the end user, he will be confused as in which client "D" he has to select. So we need to concatenate city and address to make it unique.

[image]

I am expecting an output as below.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify by providing sample data and expected results

Comment: I am adding an image. please wait.

Comment: I think images cannot be displayed.

Comment: @SorrelVesper, Can you please try again. I have verified once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT() OVER()` for this:

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        ByName = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientName),
        ByCity = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientName,ClientCity)
    FROM Client
)
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN ByName = 1 AND ByCity = 1 THEN ClientName
        WHEN ByName > 1 AND ByCity = 1 THEN ClientName + ', ' + ClientCity
        WHEN ByName > 1 AND ByCity > 1 THEN ClientName + ', ' + ClientCity + ', ' + ClientAddress
    END
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ClientID
```

**RESULT**

```
Client
--------------------------------------------------------
A
B
C, New York
D, London, LSE Houghton Streen London WC2A 2AE
D, London, Hard Rock Cafe London 150 Old Park Lane
F
C, Paris
```

See **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5ffd5/1/0)**.

Comment: Just one more question. How do I get ClientId also in the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, you can try the string concatenation using "+" operator as follows

```
select
    ClientName + ', ' + ClientCity + ', ' + ClientAddress as ClientData,
    Concat(ClientName, ', ', ClientCity, ', ', ClientAddress) Client
from client
```

The second concatenation is built using [SQL CONCAT() funtion](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-concat-string-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) will work on SQL Server 2012 and later

For the conditional data following SELECT statement can help,

```
select
--  ClientName + ', ' + ClientCity + ', ' + ClientAddress as ClientData,
--  Concat(ClientName, ', ', ClientCity, ', ', ClientAddress) ClientDtata2,
    client = 
    case when count(*) over (partition by ClientName) = 1 then ClientName
    else 
        case when count(*) over (partition by ClientName, ClientCity) = 1 then CONCAT(ClientName, ', ' , ClientCity)
        else Concat(ClientName, ', ', ClientCity, ', ', ClientAddress)
        end
    end
from client
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS,

```
Declare @t table (clientid int identity(1,1),clientname varchar(50),clientCITY varchar(50)
,clientaddress varchar(200))
insert into @t values ('A','PARIS','DFSDFSDF'), ('C','NEW YORK','DFSDFSDF')
,('C','PARIS','WEQWEQWE'),('D','LONDON','QWE342'),('D','LONDON','21DXCXZC')
;With CTE as

(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by clientname order by clientid)rn
,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by clientname,ClientCity order by clientid)rn1

 from @T A
)
--select * from cte
select  clientname+','+ clientCITY
from cte A  WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT CLIENTID FROM CTE WHERE clientname=A.clientname AND    RN>1 AND RN1<=1)

UNION ALL

select  clientname+','+ clientaddress
from cte A  WHERE 
EXISTS(SELECT CLIENTID FROM CTE WHERE clientname=A.clientname AND    RN1>1)

UNION ALL

select  clientname
from cte A  WHERE not 
EXISTS  (SELECT CLIENTID FROM CTE WHERE clientname=A.clientname AND    RN>1 )
```